# <input type="file"> onChange calls js out of mutliple <script>-Tags

Tags: javascript, function, onchange

I'm making an upload-page, where you can upload file by dropping it onto an area as well as by clicking on an image and choosing a file.
It works great, but now I want to implement a progressbar, so I have to call a js-function in the onChange-Event of the chooseFile-button:

```
<img src="images/cloud.png" id="uploadCloud" class="uploadImage" alt="Dateien durchsuchen"/>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="datei" name="datei" onChange="javascript:upload()" hidden/>
    </form>
```

These are my scripts:

```
<script>
    function upload()
    {
        //Do stuff to upload file (already implemented)
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e)
    {
        $("#uploadCloud").click(function()
        {
            $("#datei").trigger('click');
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Testing the code, the console throws a `ReferenceError: upload is not defined`

I can't see where my differs from this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

What have I done wrong calling the `upload()` function?

Comment: can you share where the script tags are placed in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just type `onChange="upload()"` instead of `onChange="javascript:upload()"` but the better unobtrusive way would be

```
<head>
<script>

    upload = function() {

    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#datei").change(upload);
        $("#uploadCloud").click(function()
        {
            $("#datei").trigger('click');
        });
    }); 

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="images/cloud.png" id="uploadCloud" class="uploadImage" alt="Dateien durchsuchen"/>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="datei" name="datei" />
    </form> 

</body>
```

Comment: @PanCave feel free to mark this as correct if you it worked correctly for you

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the point of *javascript:onchange();* and that *hidden* word there...

```
<img src="images/cloud.png" id="uploadCloud" class="uploadImage" alt="Dateien durchsuchen"/>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="datei" name="datei" onchange="upload()" />
</form>
```

Comment: the javascript: was from previous coding and the hidden was important, because I onla want to show the progressbar once the upload started

Comment: Ok, just telling, the problem was caused by the *javascript:* thing and If the progress bar appears with the function, it won't be shown until you call it